# Macro to merge cells in a column if the same rows are merged in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba, merge

I need help finding a macro that can merge cells across rows in a column if those same rows are already merged in another column.  Below is a screenshot of what I have now that shows the cells that are merged in Column `A`.

[image: before]

The below screenshot is what I need the spreadsheet to look like after the macro runs; the corresponding cells in Column `B` are merged.

[image: after]

Comment: Welcome to superuser, as always: What have you tried so far? Do you have some VBA code with an actual problem where you stuck?

Comment: No VBA now just because I don't have too much experience with writing VBA.  I have tried to solve with using the CONCATENATE function in column B referencing the cells in column A with the criteria of being merged, but so far have been unsuccessful.  I searched related posts on Superuser for macros to potentially solve this, but have not been able to find macros that merge cells referencing other merged cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the shortest I could make. I tried it with your example and it worked for me.

```
Sub mergecolumn()

Dim cnt As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim str As String

For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    cnt = Cells(i, 1).MergeArea.Count
    Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i - cnt + 1, 2))

    For Each cl In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cl) Then str = str + vbNewLine + cl
    Next
    If str <> "" Then str = Right(str, Len(str) - 2)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    rng.Merge
    rng = str
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    str = ""
    i = i - cnt + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Once I knew a better/shorter way to concatenate cells. It was something with join, split, array and range. Dammit, I forgot it.

Comment: Thanks so much!  The VB worked perfectly.  Thanks again for your help!