# Update to: Macro to merge cells in a column if the same rows are merged in a different column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros, merge

I have a large (over 10k rows) spreadsheet with text data I want to concatenate from multiple rows into a single row. The text data corresponds to a date that is in a merged cell in a neighboring column, however the corresponding text associated to a specific date is listed in various numbers of rows. I cannot figure out how to write a code that will take into account the varying number of rows.

I tried the macro in the link below, but with the entire project it gives me the following error:
Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch

It will work if I break it up into small chunks, but even then it might work in maybe one in ten tries.

I have screen shots, but it won't let me post the images without rep points

[Macro to merge cells in a column if the same rows are merged in a different column](https://superuser.com/questions/612000/macro-to-merge-cells-in-a-column-if-the-same-rows-are-merged-in-a-different-colu?newreg=b73fe73a4ed44483b12b18c4fa87a470)

Comment: Share your screenshots using a free img host and post the links.  Then a user with high rep will do a suggested edit to add the pictures.

Comment: Where does the error occur? What do you think the error means? Is there a pattern to where the data you want to concatenate resides?