# Dynamic Vertical Cell merge, in VBA or Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am getting data with a row for each item ordered per person who ordered it.  I am trying to consolidate that to just one row of the person and a merge of the items ordered

original data in spread sheet:
[image: original data in spread sheet]

The end goal of the data:
[image: The end goal of the data]

From looking at your answer to ... 
[Macro to merge cells in a column if the same rows are merged in a different column](https://superuser.com/questions/612000/macro-to-merge-cells-in-a-column-if-the-same-rows-are-merged-in-a-different-colu)

I have an idea of what to do.

I could first, try and merge all the names to one cell and then, I have a situation in that post above. Though I am not sure how I might do that.  Would if be an if clause A1=A2, A1&'', that is not quite working for me right now.

So any help with this would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you should just rethink your output and use a pivot table with names in rows and order item in columns then the data area would contain the count. However, if you are set on that output then I think the formula combination of `=if(countifs()>1,"A,","")&if(countifs()>1,"B,","")&...` in column B

Comment: This can be done easily with the newer functions available (TEXTJOIN and UNIQUE) but if you are going to try a VBA solution, remember to work from the bottom to the top in your code.

Comment: @jeeped, what is this UNIQUE you speak of...it's not showing up in the functions (latest excel version).

Comment: @gns100 - It's the new [UNIQUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e). However, given that specific data a unique list could be derived with `=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($2:$99)/(B$2:B$99="customer order"),ROW(1:1)))`.

Comment: This can be solve by using UDF or even TEXTJOIN,, but the issue is `Customer Order` in between,,,!!

Answer (score 0):

*Combination of `UDF` & `SUBSTITUTE` can solve the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put `0` in Cell `I236` & formula in Cell `I237:`

`=IF(G236=G237,I236+1,0)` ,*fill it down.*

- Either press **A**lt+F11 or **R**ight click the **S**heet TAB & hit **V**iew Code to **O**pen VB Editor.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this VBA code as **M**odule.

  ```
  Function SingleCellValue(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)

  Dim i As Long
  Dim xRet As String
  For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
      If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
          If xRet = "" Then
              xRet = LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & Char
          Else
              xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & Char
          End If
      End If
  Next
  SingleCellValue = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
  End Function
  ```
- Write formula in Cell `H249:`

`=SingleCellValue(G249,G236:H246,2,",")`

- Final formula in Cell `I249:`

`=SUBSTITUTE(H249, "Cust. Order,", "", 1)`

*Fill formula down.*

**N.B.**

- For neatness later on you may hide values in Cell `H249:H251`.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.